# Does the numerical range contain all eigenvalues in infinite dimensions?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

In finite dimensions, the [numerical range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range#Properties) $$W(T) := \left\{ \frac{x^* T x}{x^* x}: x \in \mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\}\right\}$$ of an matrix $T \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ contains all eigenvalues of $T$.

In infinite dimensions (a complex Hilbert space $(\mathcal{H}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$) we define the numerical range of a linear continuous operator $T \in L(\mathcal{H})$:
$$
W(T)
:= \{ \langle Tx, x \rangle: \| x \| = 1\}. 
$$
Let $\sigma(T)$ denote the spectrum of $T$, then we know that $\sigma(T) \subset \overline{W(T)}$ (we actually also have $\sigma(T) \subset W(T)$ in finite dimensions). Does $W(T)$ also contain all eigenvalues in this case or does only $\overline{W(T)}$ contain all eigenvalues?

**My ideas:**
Let $\lambda \in \mathcal{C}$ be an eigenvalue. Then there exists a vector $x \ne 0$ such that $Tx = \lambda x$.
Now $\tilde{x} := \frac{1}{\| x \|} x$ has unit norm and we have
$$
\langle T \tilde{x}, \tilde{x} \rangle
= \frac{1}{\| x \|^2}  \langle Tx, x \rangle
= | \lambda |.
$$

Is my proof correct or do I have to get rid of the absolute value somehow?

Comment: You don't need to work with the original $x$. If $Tx = \lambda x$, then $Ty = \lambda y$ for any $y = \alpha x$ where $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ so you can just assume that $x$ is normalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation is wrong. $\langle Tx,x \rangle=\lambda \langle x,x \rangle$ so  you actually get $\lambda$ instead of $|\lambda|$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Inner product is linear in first variable and conjugate linear in second variable. Here we have a consatnt only in the first variable so it just comes out as it is.

Comment: Ok, it is the other way around on the [German wikipedia page for scalar product](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skalarprodukt#Definition_(Axiomatik)) but I remember now that in class we also defined it that way. Thank you. So apart from that my proof is correct?

Comment: Yes, your only mistake is in adding the asolute value sign. @ViktorGlombik